# Calling a function defined in an included js file in windows.onload

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the scenario. I have written some functions in a js file common.js and included it above another js file let's name it x.js

Now when I try to call those functions (written in common.js) in x.js under the window.onload function - an error pops out in the console saying reference error:  not defined.

Now even I tried to use an alert in common.js - it does not pop out ?

Comment: maybe you can find here the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Comment: Please, make a clear question. Show some code. I can just say you forgot to add common.js to your html, but I have no idea if I'm right.

Comment: Nope i did not forget to add js file, obviously not my friend - It appears to be a known issue. @markus the link you gave worked :). Posting the solution as the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - Thanks @markus for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file).

To this to solve such a problem:
Put content of x.js content withing these:

```
$.getScript("common.js", function(){


   // everything inside x.js here 

});
```

Now just include x.js (updated) in your html